# Dense_rank not ranking correctly in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, dense-rank

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ID, Version_Number,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY id, version_number DESC) AS Recency
FROM 
    table 
WHERE
    ID = '41710288'
```

Below is the incorrect result I get:

```
ID         Version_Number   Recency
------------------------------------
41710288    10               2
41710288     9               1
```

The correct result should be

```
ID        Version_Number    Recency
------------------------------------
41710288    10               1
41710288     9               2
```

I know you might suggest me to change the order by to `ASC` from `DESC`. But that's not the real issue.

I validated and confirm that this script is working for all other records properly, except for few records that has `version_number` 10 and 9. In all records where `version_number` is 10 and 9 I face this issue.

Can you please help me with it?

Comment: it looks like your version number field is stored as a string and not a number -- convert it to a number before using it to sort by.

Comment: I [can't replicate](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b6d57c5cff3cb9cc5b4f61387b105db8) your problem (assuming `Version_Number` is a numerical data type).

Comment: @Hogan - You are right , i have both of them in nvarchar. I used cast(deal_id as float),cast(deal_version_number as float) and that fixed the problem

Comment: @Larnu - thanks for your support , my data type was nvarchar i think that caused the issue.

Comment: I would suggest castint int if you can -- less chance of getting a  parsing error.  Also it is often the case that the "rounding" on floats can cause bugs

Answer (score 0):

`version_number()` would appear to be a string.  Try converting it:

```
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY ID
                       ORDER BY id, TRY_CONVERT(int, version_number) DESC
                      ) AS Recency
```